# Slow Query in Wordpress Administrator

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization, wordpress-rest-api

I have a WordPress site with a large user db more than 1 million users.

I am seeing a slow query in the logs and it looks like this:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID
                FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )
                WHERE 1=1 AND ( 
  ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value != '0' )
)
                ORDER BY display_name ASC
                LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I want to find what is triggering it and stop it from executing this query. (Listing admins and authors is not something I'm intending on using.

I have already tried the below with no luck:

```
add_action('init', function () {
        foreach (['page', 'post', 'wh_jobs', 'wh_edu', 'wh_glossary'] as $type) {
            remove_post_type_support($type, 'author');
        }        
    });
```

Comment: Try these plugins:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/ and  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-users-for-speed/

Comment: And, the query you showed us comes from an old plugin. What plugin? Please [edit] your question. WordPress core now uses `wp_capabilities` rather than `wp_user_level`.